# How to save a text file received in a POST request using python

Tags: python, post, basehttpserver

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import SocketServer


class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers.getheader('content-length')))
        print data
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>POST!</h1></body></html>")

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=8080):
    server_address = ('localhost', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print 'Starting server'
    httpd.serve_forever()

run()
```

This is my server code. The post requests I receive contain a text file and other key:value pairs.This prints the whole content including the content of the text file. How can I save that text file on my hard drive..?
Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ['hey there']
with open('filehere.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in data:
        file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

I hope that is at least some kind of a guideline.

Comment: It does the job to an extent. But it writes the whole content to the file. I want to extract the file that is received. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding an if statement which looks for a text file