# Save file received from POST request in Python

Tags: python, post, file-upload, simplehttpserver

I'm trying to implement an upload feature to the basic [http.server](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/af441df3ff0eab7bce782011cf702a8a9005da1f/Lib/http/server.py) Python module.

So far, I've created a new class named `SimpleHTTPRequestHandlerWithUpload` which inherits from `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and added an upload section to `list_directory()`. The next step would be creating a `do_POST()` method, which handles the request and saves the file inside the current working directory. However, I have no idea how to do this. I looked at [UniIsland's code](https://gist.github.com/UniIsland/3346170) on GitHub but I can't understand what he did and the code is very old. I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622564/how-to-save-a-text-file-received-in-a-post-request-using-python) and tried to implement it in my code.

It kind of works, but the file is "littered" with headers. This does not pose a big problem on txt files, but it corrupts all of the other file extensions.

**I'd like to know how to remove the headers, save the uploaded file inside the current working directory with its original name and check if the upload was successful or not.**

This is my code:

```
__version__ = '0.1'

import http.server
import html
import io
import os
import socket  # For gethostbyaddr()
import sys
import urllib.parse
import contextlib

from http import HTTPStatus


class SimpleHTTPRequestHandlerWithUpload(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    server_version = 'SimpleHTTPWithUpload/' + __version__

    def do_POST(self):
        """Serve a POST request."""
        data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['content-length']))
        with open('file.txt', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(data)
        r = []
        enc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
        r.append('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">')
        r.append("<html>\n<title>Upload Result Page</title>\n")
        r.append("<body>\n<h2>Upload Result Page</h2>\n")
        r.append("</body>\n</html>")
        encoded = '\n'.join(r).encode(enc, 'surrogateescape')
        f = io.BytesIO()
        f.write(encoded)
        f.seek(0)
        self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(encoded)))
        self.end_headers()
        if f:
            self.copyfile(f, self.wfile)
            f.close()

    def list_directory(self, path):
        """Helper to produce a directory listing (absent index.html).
        Return value is either a file object, or None (indicating an
        error).  In either case, the headers are sent, making the
        interface the same as for send_head().
        """
        try:
            list = os.listdir(path)
        except OSError:
            self.send_error(
                HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                'No permission to list directory')
            return None
        list.sort(key=lambda a: a.lower())
        r = []
        try:
            displaypath = urllib.parse.unquote(self.path,
                                               errors='surrogatepass')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            displaypath = urllib.parse.unquote(path)
        displaypath = html.escape(displaypath, quote=False)
        enc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
        title = 'Directory listing for %s' % displaypath
        r.append('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" '
                 '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">')
        r.append('<html>\n<head>')
        r.append('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" '
                 'content="text/html; charset=%s">' % enc)
        r.append('<title>%s</title>\n</head>' % title)
        r.append('<body>\n<h1>%s</h1>' % title)
        r.append('<hr>\n<ul>')
        for name in list:
            fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
            displayname = linkname = name
            # Append / for directories or @ for symbolic links
            if os.path.isdir(fullname):
                displayname = name + '/'
                linkname = name + '/'
            if os.path.islink(fullname):
                displayname = name + '@'
                # Note: a link to a directory displays with @ and links with /
            r.append('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' % (urllib.parse.quote(linkname, errors='surrogatepass'),
                                                       html.escape(displayname, quote=False)))
        r.append('</ul>\n<hr>\n')
        r.append('<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#">\n'
                 '<input id="fileupload" name="file" type="file" />\n'
                 '<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />\n'
                 '</form>')
        r.append('\n<hr>\n</body>\n</html>\n')
        encoded = '\n'.join(r).encode(enc, 'surrogateescape')
        f = io.BytesIO()
        f.write(encoded)
        f.seek(0)
        self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=%s' % enc)
        self.send_header('Content-Length', str(len(encoded)))
        self.end_headers()
        return f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class DualStackServer(http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer):
        def server_bind(self):
            # suppress exception when protocol is IPv4
            with contextlib.suppress(Exception):
                self.socket.setsockopt(
                    socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_V6ONLY, 0)
            return super().server_bind()

    http.server.test(
        HandlerClass=SimpleHTTPRequestHandlerWithUpload,
        ServerClass=DualStackServer
    )
```

If you want to test it, just run the script on your machine, open a web browser on a different machine and type in the address bar `<IP_ADDRESS_1>:8000` where `IP_ADDRESS_1` is the IP of the machine you're running the code on.

Please, tell me if there's something wrong with it other than the `do_POST()` method. I'm a new Python programmer and I'm trying to improve my software design skills in general. Thank you!

---

EDIT: I figured out how to remove the headers and save the file with its original name. However, the script hangs on `data = self.rfile.readlines()` until I close the browser tab and then works well. I don't know what to do. It seems I have to send some sort of EOF to notify `readlines()` that I'm finished sending the file but I have no clue how to do it. I also can't figure out how to check if the file has been uploaded successfully or not. Any help is appreciated!

Updated `do_POST()` method:

```
def do_POST(self):
    """Serve a POST request."""
    data = self.rfile.readlines()
    filename = re.findall(r'Content-Disposition.*name="file"; filename="(.*)"', str(data[1]))
    if len(filename) == 1:
        filename = ''.join(filename)
    else:
        return
    data = data[4:-2]
    data = b''.join(data)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(data)
    r = []
    enc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
    r.append('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" '
             '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">')
    r.append('<html>\n<title>Upload result page</title>\n')
    r.append('<body>\n<h2>Upload result page</h2>\n')
    r.append('</body>\n</html>')
    encoded = '\n'.join(r).encode(enc, 'surrogateescape')
    f = io.BytesIO()
    f.write(encoded)
    f.seek(0)
    self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    self.send_header('Content-Length', str(len(encoded)))
    self.end_headers()
    if f:
        self.copyfile(f, self.wfile)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve all of my problems. I posted my [code](https://github.com/sgrontflix/simplehttpserverwithupload) on GitHub, for anyone interested.